# Wait for a textbox / keyboard input before populating a dropdown (Kendo + ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a .net web application that currently has a hardcoded url to read different data in to dropdown lists. I want to avoid hardcoding urls and instead read from a textbox/input, is there a way to do this with javascript?

I was thinking about having the url be read after the user presses enter key after entering in their data.

This is how I'm populating dropdown/comboboxes with kendo in the view

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(x => x.LayerName)
.Name("Layers")
    .DataTextField("Text")
          .DataValueField("Value")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
          .Filter("contains")
          .DataSource(source =>
          {
              source.Read(read =>
              {
                  read.Action("GetServices", "ArcGISRest");//.Data("GetURL");
              })
              .ServerFiltering(true);
          }));
```

I was originally trying to use the GetURL method that pretty much gets the url from the input box using jquery. However, because this is the server side logic when the url is grabbed it is by default empty (obviously).

I've also considered using a button to do an ajax post and populate that way but that seems excessive. There must be a simpler way to handle this?

The user would be submitting one url and dealing with the data obtained from that url so it wouldnt be them putting in one url and then changing to another one (at least not right now).

So any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to wait for user input, then you need to get the drop-down choices via AJAX. I'm not familiar enough with Kendo to give you exact code, but essentially, you should just pass the `ComboBoxFor` method no options or an empty list of options, however that would be achieved.

Then, client-side, you can handle the change event of the input that determines what URL to hit, and use the relevant Kendo JavaScript to build your select list there. See: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/addnewitem.

Comment: This is actually how I ended up going about this, but it looks like a kendo has a way to reload your comboboxes by calling read again, so I decided to go with the empty list of options initially and then when a user submits the url it reloads the combobox and populates. Thanks for the suggestion!